# Designing a model in rails which needs to be verified before updating/creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several `forms` where users can send data for approval to `admin`. Once admin approves only then the approved data is created/updated in the real table.

> (eg: a model with bank details for user. Once admin approves only then
>   the data is used). So how to structure the backend for this?

My initial thoughts:

**1st approach**

Let's say as per the eg above we have a banking model for saving the bank details.

```
def BankingModel
 belongs_to :user
end
```

As it needs to be verified by admin initially it won't be saved to the banking model. Instead, I create an exact replica of the table that it is supposed to be saved and save it initially there

```
def ProposedBankingModel
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Once admin click approves then the data is copied to the bankingmodel table.

**Cons of this approach:**

- Unnecessary maintenance of a table for each `table/data`
- need to create separate modal like `proposed_some_table` for each model that needs to change

I have a feeling this is a bit overkill

**2nd approach**

Here only one model will be used. So as per the example when sending a new create/update of a record the requested data will be saved on the service_request model itself.

```
def service_request
 id: db_table_id, 
 request_model: banking_model// decides which model its for, here its banking model
 requested_data:jsonb//contains data as json, 
 status: pending#shows approval status
end
```

Here the request type will decide which model to update &  on approval by admin the `json` from the service_request will be used to fill the model of the request_type, here the `BankingModel`.

I found the second approach better. but I need to manually loop through the json for each field after approving for updating in the real table. But I think I can structure jsonb exactly based on the `requestmodel` type before saving which so it can look for `:key :value` for each table fields.

Is the direction am going right? Any suggestions?

Also is there a library available for doing the same in rails so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to be to just add a `ActiveRecord::Enum` to the model:

```
class AddStatusToBankingModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :banking_models, :status, :integer, default: 0, index: true
  end
end
```

Note `default: 0`.

```
class BankingModel
  enum status: {
    0: :pending,
    1: :approved,
    2: :on_hold # just an example
  }
end
```

You can then approve a record by calling `record.approved!` or `record.update(status: :approved)`. As to the rest of your question its kind of incomprehensible but I guess you could use nested attributes or the proxy pattern to approve a "banking model" that belongs to a service request.

> Also is there a library available for doing the same in rails so I
>   don't have to reinvent the wheel? Thank you

Again somewhat unclear what you are actually doing. But you might not actually need any additional dependencies. If the logic of actually flipping the switch between pending and approved is complex you might want to look into [state machines](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines).

Comment: This method works fine when creating records for the first time. But during updation of any values by user it will be updating the already approved table. I want approved data values in table to remain unchanged until admin approves the newly updated value

Comment: Also I think this can be solved by creating a new row to the table with pending status and once approved remove the previously approved one. Also table validations with one approved data & one pending status at any given time will be good I think

Comment: But this way there could be a possible case of error if the deleted table id is referenced  in a has many/belongs_to association model  or similar